# Criteria for Ideal of a Hopf Algebra to Yield Closed Subgroup

Tags: algebraic-groups, affine-schemes

Let $k$ be a commutative ring with unity, and let $A$ be the $k$-algebra of an affine group scheme over $k,$ endowed with its usual structure as a Hopf algebra over $k.$ In Waterhouse's textbook, *An Introduction to Affine Group Schemes*, he discusses the criteria that an ideal $I$ of $A$ must satisfy in order for $A/I$ to represent a closed subgroup scheme. These conditions are

1) If $\Delta$ is the comultiplication, then $\Delta(I) \subseteq A \otimes_k I + I \otimes_k A$.

2) If $S$ is the antipode, then $S(I) \subseteq I$.

3) If $\epsilon$ is the augmentation, then $\epsilon(I) = 0.$

I understand that 3) is both necessary and sufficient for the unit element(s) to belong to the subgroup scheme. I also understand that 1) is sufficient for closure under multiplication for the subgroup scheme and that 2) is sufficient for closure under inversion for the subgroup scheme.

I am guessing that 2) is necessary for closure under inversion because we can just consider the canonical projection $A \to A/I,$ which is a map with kernel equal to $I.$

However, I am confused as to why 1) is necessary for closure under multiplication.

That is, if it is true that for every $k$-algebra $R$ and for every $f, g : A \to R$ with $f(I) = 0 = g(I)$ that we have $\left((f \otimes g) \circ \Delta\right) = 0$, then why must condition 1) follow?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think that I can do sort of the same thing. Namely let $f = g = \pi : A \to A/I.$ Then $(\pi \otimes_k \pi) \circ \Delta$ vanishes on $I.$ Hence, $\Delta(I) \subseteq \ker(\pi \otimes_k \pi).$ Now, one must show $\ker(\pi \otimes_k \pi) \subseteq A \otimes_k I + I \otimes_k A.$ Unfortunately, I am not sure how to show this last step. (The reverse inclusion is clear to me, but that is not what is needed.)

Comment: We want $\Delta$ to descend to an algebra homorphism $A/I \to A/I \otimes A/I$. So I think it must boil down to: suppose $M' \subset M$, and $N' \subset N$ are $k$-modules. Then $M/M' \otimes N/N' \simeq M\otimes N / (M'\otimes N + M \otimes N')$. Agree?

Comment: Namely, the iso above seems correct to me - or am I being stupid?

Comment: I think I see what you mean...but is it clear to you that equality holds for the kernel in the map of my comment? I can’t figure out how to prove the other inclusion...

Comment: Just to acknowledge that I saw your comment: I'll try to get back to you on this  tonight or tomorrow night...

Comment: Thanks, I think what I’m asking is a special case of what you said in your second comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments: we want $\Delta \colon A \to A\otimes A $ to descend to $\Delta \colon A/I \to A/I \otimes A/I$.

Condition 1) implies this (and is equivalent to the descent of $\Delta$) if the natural map 
$$ A\otimes A / (A\otimes I + I \otimes A) \to A/I \otimes A/I,$$
defined and determined  by $$ a\otimes b\mapsto \overline a \otimes \overline b,$$ 
is an isomorphism, where $\overline x = x + I$.

More generally, and for clarity, again as in the comment section, if $M'\subset M$, $N'\subset N$ are $k$-modules, we want to show that the natural map 
 $$ M\otimes N / (M'\otimes N + M \otimes N') \to M/M' \otimes N/N',$$
defined/determined by
$$ m\otimes n + (M'\otimes N + M \otimes N') \to \overline m \otimes \overline n$$
is an isomorphism (and $\overline m = m + M'$, and similarly for $n$).
Just to give this last map a name, call it $\alpha$.

To construct an inverse map $\beta$:

Fix $m \in M$. Then there is a $k$-linear map
$$\phi_m \colon N \to M\otimes N / (M'\otimes N + M \otimes N') ,$$
defined by 
 $$\phi_m\colon n \to m \otimes n  + (M'\otimes N + M \otimes N').$$
Clearly, $\phi_m$ vanishes on $N'$, so $\phi_m$ descends to a $k$-linear map 
 - call it $\phi_m$ again - abuse of notation: 
$$ \phi_m \colon \bar n \to m\otimes n +   (M'\otimes N + M \otimes N').$$

Now, $m \to \phi_m$ is $k$-linear, and depends only on $\bar m$, so we obtain a $k$-bilinear map
$$ M/M' \times N/N' \to M \otimes N / (M'\otimes N + M \otimes N'),$$
with 
$$ (\bar m,\bar n) \to (m\otimes n) + (M'\otimes N + M \otimes N').$$
Therefore, by definition (defining property of tensor products) one has the desired $k$-linear map $\beta$ 
$$ M/M' \otimes N/N' \to M \otimes N / (M'\otimes N + M \otimes N').$$

On generators, the two maps $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are inverses, so $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $k$-module inverses.

Comment: I see, thank you. I was hoping to somehow get away with showing that it is injective (and thus an isomorphism) without explicitly constructing an inverse.

Comment: Yes - I figured as much... Enjoy the book. I remember it being v. good (I have to admit that I didn't read the smoothness section, and am sorry that I never did).